# What are the security concerns for exposing Electron's ipcRenderer to a embedded webview?

Tags: javascript, security, events, webview, electron

Currently I'm am trying to facilitate communication between a desktop Electron app and a remote web application embedded in a Electron webview. For security purposes, nodeintegration must be kept disabled on the webview.

However, ipcRenderer requires node, and therefore any event listeners on the webapp side must be loaded in a preload script. This is undesirable. A work around I found is to simply expose to the web application the ipcRenderer itself. Like so:

someDesktopScript.js

```
webview.send("testNote", "test");
```

preload.js

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

class iTest { 
    ipcInterfaceTest() {
        return ipcRenderer;
    }
}

let local = new iTest ();
window.desktop = {local};
```

webApp script:

```
window.desktop.local.ipcInterfaceTest().on(testNote, (event, stuff) => {
    //stuff
}
```

I feel as though this isn't a good idea and may open up other security issues. If so, is there a way to resolve this, or a better work around I am unaware of that achieves the same result?

Otherwise, is this safe to do? MY knowledge of how much of a security liability Electron's ipcRenderer is, is limited.